# Access other attributes in the same subobject in semantic-mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I am using subproperties in semantic mediawiki to store different kinds of information, e.g. a log.
This can look like this:

```
{{#subobject:
 |Has date = 2020-06-18
 |Has log = Diary
 |Has tag = Stackoverflow
 |Has agenda = 
* Done Something
}}
```

What I would like to do is to use an #ask query inside of the agenda part that accesses the date parameter, like this:

```
{{#subobject:
 |Has date = 2020-06-18
 |Has log = Diary
 |Has tag = Stackoverflow
 |Has agenda = 
* The date today is:

{{#ask:
[[Has log::Diary]]
[[Has date::<<Is there a way to access the date of this subobject?>>]]
|?Has date = Date
}}

}}
```

I know that this is not possible directly, since the text has to be stored in the database first in order to retrieve it later, but I would not mind if I had to save it twice or need another workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: How is the first date entered? Manually, Extension:Page forms? Why would you duplicate the date information? If the "Has agenda" property is not intended to be query through api, there is no need to do that...

Comment: The first date is entered manually like in the first code example. The background is rather that I have another set of information that also has a date attribute. Now, whenever I am doing an entry in this log, I would like to fetch information from the other dataset with a template like `{{Include_Other_Dataset|date=<<This is where I would like to include the query information of the subobject's date>>}}`

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to wrap this code in a template, say `Template:Appointment`:

```
<includeonly>{{#subobject:
 |Has date = {{{date|}}}
 |Has log = {{{log|}}}
 |Has tag = {{{tag|}}}
 |Has agenda = {{{agenda|}}}
}}

Also on {{{date|}}} in {{{log|}}}:
{{#ask:
[[Has log::{{{log|}}}]]
[[Has date::{{date|}}}]]
|?Has date = Date
|format = ul
}}
</includeonly>
```

The call the template like

```
{{Appointment
| date   = 2020-06-18
| log    = Diary
| tag    = Stackoverflow
| agenda = <nowiki>
* The date today is:
}}
```

whenever you want to add records to log.